# Django/DRF filtering

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I filter my list of Product models by title field. For example, I want to find this title = 'Happy cake'. And if I type

Case 1. 'happy cake',

Case 2. 'hapy cake', happi kake'

it should return me  'Happy cake'.As I know icontains helps me with case 1. How can I get that?May be some sort of technologies should be added or django itself has appropriate solution?

Comment: That cases I mentioned earlier are not complete. I mean any mistake like typo or misspell may be in requested title, but mostly similar titles should be returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of question is hard to solve by just using Django inbuild search system. So this is one way to solve this question. ElasticSearch. It has fuzzy search and indexing. Cool thing to deal with tough tasks). I pushed to [git](https://github.com/aabce/tella_task) some starting code. It doesn't solve this question fully, but with some workaround that goal can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the lookup `__in`

```
Model.objects.filter(title__in=['happy cake', 'happi kake'])
```

You can put as many test cases you want in the list.

Comment: Thank you!But does it mean that I should write all the possible cases as __in argument?What if I have title with 10 words?

Comment: Yeah, just keep appending your cases inside the `__in` argument. My suggestion would be to build a list first, and then pass it in, `my_test_cases = ['case1', 'case2', 'case3', 'case4'] query = Model.objects.filter(title__in=my_test_cases)`

Comment: May be some extra technology? To hard code every case sounds a little bit weird)

Comment: Well usually in my cases I have these test cases supplied by the user itself, otherwise I do hardcode them. But there are way smarter people than I am and they must have a better solution. This is the best solution I have got though. If you'd like you can accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this other way.

If you are sure about the start *ha* here

**Ha**ppy Cake

**Ha**py cake

**ha**ppi kake

```
Product.objects.filter(title__startswith='ha')
```

Comment: Thank you) But all fun starts when <<god user>> forgets to type h))

Comment: then you are giving too much space for error even if it works for some cases your logic will fail because you dont have sure filtering criteria.